# Why isn't Julia overwriting the Array value?

Tags: arrays, image-processing, julia, global

I have a array for an image I cropped using a function I made called `contourCrop()`, but when I try to change the individual values of the array using a loop the values remain the same. For example, the value of `mat2[122, 411]` is still 0.027450980392156862 even though that is less than 0.2. Oddly enough though if I change `global mat2[r, c] = 0;` to something like `global mat2[r, c] = 200;` the array elements do not change, but if I display the image using `imshow()` the image changes. Is there an easy way I can change the array values of the image manually?

```
img = load("C:\\Users\\josep\\Downloads\\archive\\no\\2 no.jpeg");
imgg = Gray.(img);
mat = convert(Array{Float64}, imgg);

mat2 = contourCrop(mat);


for r in size(mat2, 1), c in size(mat2, 2)
    if mat2[r, c] < 0.2
        global mat2[r, c] = 0;
    end
end

println(mat2[122, 411]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably that `size` gives an integer, not a range, and thus `for r in size(mat2, 1)` iterates over just one value. You could write `1:size(mat2, 1)`, or better, use `axes`:

```
julia> mat2 = randn(2,5)
2×5 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.426329   0.153334   2.50947   0.669216  -0.51994
 -1.08846   -1.16639   -0.786405  0.451461  -1.893

julia> for r in axes(mat2, 1), c in axes(mat2, 2)
           if mat2[r, c] < 0.2
               mat2[r, c] = 0;
           end
       end

julia> mat2
2×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.426329  0.0  2.50947  0.669216  0.0
 0.0       0.0  0.0      0.451461  0.0
```

Or perhaps better, write `mat2 .= mat2 .* (mat2 .< 0.2)` or something like `map!(x -> x<0.2 ? 0 : x, mat2, mat2)`.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you for pointing that out. I thought I was going crazy, but I just overlooked something simple. Your suggested code looks a lot more elegant I give those a try.

Answer (score 1):

I executed the following the following a file using VSCode:

```
using Images
using TestImages

function contourCrop(img::Array{T,2}) where {T}
    return img[1:1000,1:1000]
end

img = testimage("earth_apollo17")
imgg = Gray.(img)
mat = convert(Array{Float64}, imgg)

mat2 = contourCrop(mat)
mat2[122, 411] = 0.027450980392156862

for r in size(mat2, 1), c in size(mat2, 2)
    println("r: $r, c: $c")
    if mat2[r,c] < 0.2
        global mat2[r,c] = 0;
    end
end

println(mat2[122, 411])
```

Output:

```
r: 1000, c: 1000
0.027450980392156862
```

As you can see, you are not iterating over all values of r and c. Rather you just iterated over the last pixel at (r=1000,c=1000).

Let's just fix the loop first.

```
for r in 1:size(mat2, 1), c in 1:size(mat2, 2)
    #println("r: $r, c: $c")
    if mat2[r,c] < 0.2
        global mat2[r,c] = 0;
    end
end

println(mat2[122, 411])
```

Output:

```
0.0
```

Here's a better way to iterate across the image:

```
for I in CartesianIndices(mat2)
    #println("r: $(I[1]), c: $(I[2])")
    global mat2
    if mat2[I] < 0.2
        mat2[I] = 0;
    end
end

println(mat2[122, 411])
```